# Fetch data from URL and Display with HTML

Tags: jquery

I need some help with jQueury. I'm building a sidebar schedule which has a "Previous Day" and a "Next Day" button. What I want is if the user visits the website, it'll display the results for the current day (without clicking any buttons). But if the user clicks either "next" or "previous", it will show the results for the requested day.

The data is fetched from the /home/schedule/ url. For example, if the url is: /home/schedule/20130331, it'll fetch schedule signups for March 31st.

I have this code, however, it of course is not working. I'm not great with jQuery, so any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="btn-group" style="padding-bottom:3px;">
  <a href="#" id="prev" class="btn">Previous Day</a>
  <a href="#" id="next" class="btn">Next Day</a>                
</div>
<div id="displayResults" name="displayResults"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#next, #prev").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ URL::base() }}/home/schedule/' + date,
        data: date,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#displayResults').html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you define the `date` variable?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to define it. Specifically how to define it so it'll pull the date form the url query string.

Comment: Not related to your original question but don't forget about timezones (UTC) or you'll be giving out the wrong data for part of the day.

Comment: @imsiso if a user clicks the next button X times, it'll move the date X days ahead of the current date, fetching data for the new date. Same thing for the previous button.

Comment: What's `{{ URL::base }}`? Are you using some templating system?

Comment: Yes, if the user clicks it two times, it should fetch data two days from the current date.

Comment: @PaulSchreiber I'm using Laravel...it's just part of the framework.

Comment: @imsiso yes, I suppose the URL would change to pull the correct data. I just want to seamlessly be able to click the previous/next buttons and fetch the data without refreshing the page.

Comment: @imsiso that's not really feasible the way this framework utilizes URLs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27298/discussion-between-dutchcoffee-and-imsiso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the finil:

**HTML**
    
        Previous Day
        Next Day 
    
    
    **in js fiddle you wont see any change in url**

**CSS**

```
#displayResults {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var tm;//holds timer that checks changing of url
var date='';// holds the date
    $(document).ready(function(){

        getDateFromUrl();

        updateNextBack()

        tm=setInterval(function(){ // check that is the url changed
            var tmp;
            tmp=date;
            getDateFromUrl();
            if(date!=tmp){
                updateNextBack()
                changeDate();
            }
        },300);


        function updateNextBack(){// updates next and back links
            $('#next').attr('href','#'+nextDay(date));
            $('#prev').attr('href','#'+prevDay(date));
        }

        function getDateFromUrl(){//anallyse url
            var str=new String(document.location);
            date='';
            if(str.indexOf('#')>0){
                date=str.substr(str.indexOf('#')+1,str.length-str.indexOf('#'));
            }if(date==''){
                date='20130329';
            }
            date=addToDate(date,0);
        }

        function addToDate(md,i){// adds i to md and then return md
            var tmp=new String(md); // to get date in string format

            var day , month , year; // these will hold year month and day
            day=tmp.substr(6,2);
            month=parseInt(tmp.substr(4,2))-1;
            year=tmp.substr(0,4);
            var myDate=new Date();// create a date object and set its year month and day
            myDate.setFullYear(year);
            myDate.setMonth(month);
            myDate.setDate(day);

            myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+i); // adds i day to date
            md=''+myDate.getFullYear();
            md+=''+(myDate.getMonth()<9?'0':'');
            md+=''+parseInt(myDate.getMonth())-(-1);
            md+=''+(myDate.getDate()<10?'0':'');
            md+=''+parseInt(myDate.getDate());

            return md;
        }

        function nextDay(md){// you should write real function
            return addToDate(md,1);
        }

        function prevDay(md){// you should write real function
            return addToDate(md,-1);
        }

        $('#next').click(function(){// for clicking next
        // its empty !!!
        });

        $('#prev').click(function(){// for clicking prev
        // its empty !!!
        });

        function changeDate(){// uses $.get('filename',callbackfunc) to update div value related to date val
            /*$.get('getDate.php?d='+date,function(data){ // you should uncomment this when you are in server
                $('#displayResults').html(data);
            });*/

            //use this when in jsfiddle
            data='content of date:'+date;
            $('#displayResults').html(data);
        }

    });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wpKKP/4/) the working fiddle.

Comment: It almost works...one thing I noticed though is it doesn't know when it's the last day of the month. So for example, 20130331 (march 31st), it kept going forward 20130332...20130333...etc, when it should switch to 20130401.

Comment: It'd be great if you could help!

Comment: ok first come to chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27298/discussion-between-dutchcoffee-and-imsiso

Comment: I'm on mobile right now. I will be available in about 4 hours.

Comment: You betcha! Thanks for your help.